# Saving bytes xna, problems saving certain numbers

Tags: c#, xna, isolatedstorage

I'm a bit confused, here's what I've done so far:

```
public class SaveLoadSystem
{
    String SAVEFILENAME = "gameSave2.sav";
    Stats stats = new Stats();

    GameProgressInformation gameInfo = new GameProgressInformation();

    public SaveLoadSystem()
    {

        IsolatedStorageFile savegameStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        // open isolated storage, and write the savefile.
        if (savegameStorage.FileExists(SAVEFILENAME))
        {
            IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = null;
            try
            {
                fs = savegameStorage.OpenFile(SAVEFILENAME, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
            }
            catch (IsolatedStorageException e)
            {
            }

            if (fs != null)
            {

                byte[] saveBytes = new byte[256];
                int count = fs.Read(saveBytes, 0, 256);

                if (count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < stats.GetLevels; i++)
                    {
                        GameProgressInformation.LevelUnlockInfo levelInfo = new GameProgressInformation.LevelUnlockInfo();
                        // Think line below is wrong.
                        levelInfo.score = saveBytes[i * 4];
                        GameProgressInformation.levels.Add(levelInfo);

                    }
                    fs.Close();
                }

            }

        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < stats.GetLevels; i++)
            {
                GameProgressInformation.LevelUnlockInfo levelInfo = new GameProgressInformation.LevelUnlockInfo();
                GameProgressInformation.levels.Add(levelInfo);
            }
        }
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        // Save the game.

        IsolatedStorageFile savegameStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        // open isolated storage, and write the savefile.
        IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = null;
        fs = savegameStorage.OpenFile(SAVEFILENAME, System.IO.FileMode.Create);

        if (fs != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GameProgressInformation.levels.Count; i++)
            {
                byte[] scoreBytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(GameProgressInformation.levels[i].score);
                fs.Write(scoreBytes, 0, scoreBytes.Length);

            }
            fs.Close();
        }



    }
}
```

My confusion is how when loading to get all the necessary binary data but also ensure the correct data is assigned to the correct level. I'm thinking it would have to be taken in sets of 4. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just read the data in the exact same order as you wrote it.  Why are you using IsolatedStorageFileStream.Read in a method that saves a binary file?

Comment: The constructor loads the file so the read should be there. The problem I have is that the fs.read, reads the entire file at once when really I either only want one level at a time read or I want a way in which I can always ensure that the right amount of data is read at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Worked out how to do it. Had a wrong understanding of how the stream reader works.

Comment: It may be beneficial for future readers for you to elaborate a bit more on what you got wrong.